# SWT checkbox with empty text has wrong focus/allignment

Tags: java, checkbox, swt

I am trying to add a checkbox to a column in a table. This seem to work pretty well, but is seem to add focus to the empty text field to the right of the checkbox. This also causes it to be hard to align the checkbox correct in the center.

Example:

[image: Example of checbox with wrong focus]

Code:

```
    Button button = new Button(table, SWT.CHECK);
    button .setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
    button .setLayoutData(new FillLayout());
```

Is there any way to avoid that, so the empty text field to the right of the checkbox is not shown?

Comment: Post code for the empty text field also.

Comment: Which version of SWT are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314815). Try calling `button.setText("")` as suggested in one of the comments in that thread.

---

It appears to have been fixed in SWT 4.4 M6. So if you're using an older version of SWT, you may need to update.

Comment: I tried to use the button.setText("") - but it does not help.

We are using version 3.655, so think you're right that we need to update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That version is almost 5 years old, so well worth an update.